Add variable in Grafana Dashboard
I want to add a custom variable that allows me to filter the data where tag value for "process" equals to the variable value in grafana dashboard. I am able to add a custom variable to the dashboard with value options "process1", "process2" and "process3", but when I use this variable in the query as
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["Process ID"] == ${process})
it is giving me error undefined identifier process2.
Although when I replace the variable ${process} with "process2" the query works correctly and filters out the data by that particular process, but it doesn't work when I use variable.
How can I fix this issue?
I tried using the variable in the flux query as
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["Process ID"] == ${process})
but it is not working

It seems like ${process} substitutes variable without quotes. Simply use "${process}" instead

Try to use advanced variable format options:
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["Process ID"] == ${process:doublequote})

